# Where's the skybox settings un Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, lighting, skybox

[Lighting settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vk1t.png)
I can't find the skybox settings anywhere, I've watched tutorials, and all of they say it's in the Lighting settings, but there's nothing there for me.

There's nothing in the Environment settings either. Unity version is 2021.3.21

[Environment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smRfY.png)
I tried creating a new skybox, but there's nowhere to put it. I tried changing the lighting settings, profile, and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which render pipeline you have chosen.
If it is HDRP, then in Project Settings > Graphics > HDRP Global Settings you will be able to configure HDRP Sky.
If Other > Lighting > Environment > Skybox Material and Environment skybox can be set. Use Window > Rendering > Lighting to open that menu. Your Camera component must set Clear Flags to Skybox;)

You can set your skybox from code also like that:

```
//Create field for your skybox
[SerializeField] private Material skybox;

//and set it on Start method like that
public void Start()
{
    RenderSettings.skybox = skybox;
}
```

Comment: The option to change the Render pipeline is also on Project settings > Graphics right? Thanks a lot!